# Rails - fragment cache not expiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, fragment

This one has me stumped.

I have a view with a cached fragment:

```
 - cache :key=>"news" do    
   %h2 News
   - etc
```

I have a sweeper that uses:

```
def expire_home_cache
  puts "expire_home_cache"
  expire_fragment(:key => "news") 
end
```

The sweeper is called as I can see  "expire_home_cache" in the console output.

But the fragment is not updated ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this:

```
   cache("news") do    
     %h2 News
     - etc
   end
```

and...

```
def expire_home_cache
  puts "expire_home_cache"
  expire_fragment("news") 
end
```

...or try this ...

```
 - cache({:key=>"news"}) do    
   %h2 News
   - etc
```

I am thinking the issue may be that ruby or rails is having a hard time determining what the key is exactly and so the cache method and expire_fragment are generating two different cache keys.

Comment: In Rails 4.x you might also need to do `cache("news", skip_digest: true)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing `expire_fragment(:key => "news")` with `ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(:key => "news")`

No time to explain, but it worked for me.

Comment: Make sure you put --- cache_sweeper :whatever_sweeper --- in your application_controller.rb, for the above to work.

Comment: I was having an unexplainable instance where the sweeper would refuse to expire the cache for a child association until I tried this answer, and it worked. I don't understand why. The sweeper callbacks were getting called as was the expire_fragment code. Odd.

Comment: I don't know why, but I had similar results: expire_fragment(key) was not working, but when I prepended that call with logger.warn (initially just to see the output of expire_fragment) the fragment expiration suddenly works like a charm. Confusing.

Comment: Awesome tip, it works. But if you get a time, I would like to see explaination...

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is:

```
cache :news do

  ...
end
```

And then in your sweeper:

```
expire_fragment :news
```

Comment: So the key should be a symbol, not a string?

Comment: You can make it a string, or a symbol, but it doesn't need to be a hash.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you tried the timed_fragment_cache plugin as an alternative?

http://github.com/tricycle/timed_fragment_cache/tree/master

I found this to be a much simpler way of expiring fragments in my projects.